# Renaming fields in a PDF

Tags: pdf, autofill, livecycle

I have some code that is auto-filling a PDF form based on some properties.  Initially, the errors I get when running the code pertain to the fields not being found on the mapping object, but once I change them to the correct property names, the errors all show up the same, as if the fields had all been renamed to 'topmostSubform':

```
An error has occured when filling the PDF Form [14. New OLTL Employer CLE Address-Phone  

Change Form_v_1.1]. DataBinding: 'PPLPortalCommon.Consumer' does not contain a property with 

the name 'topmostSubform'.
```

I made the edits using Adobe Livecycle Designer, so it seems something in there corrupted the field names.  Has anyone come across this issue?  Seems like a pretty simple task to change the field names.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The forms appears to have a binding issue. I believe the answer to your questions requires more questions.

1. Are you using an XSD for the data-binding ?
2. Do you have a subform named "topmostSubform" in your form template or the XSD ?

A reference is being made in the field ( either by the form template, the schema or the data-binding reference if you are not using a schema) and needs to be resolved in the template.

Unfortunately since there is no template attached to this question, I wont be able to provide any further assistance with the knowledge in hand.

Thanks,
Armaghan.